# Error converting month number to month name in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, filter

i used this filter to convert month number to month name and its works fine :

```
.filter('monthName', [function() {
 return function (monthNumber) { //1 = January
var monthNames = [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
  'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ];
return monthNames[monthNumber - 1];
```

}

View:

```
 <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="dataf"
        chart-labels={{labelsf | monthName}} chart-series="seriesf" chart-options="options"
        chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-click="onClick">
</canvas>
```

but it gives me this error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:26794 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{labelsf] starting at [{labelsf].
```

can anybody please tell me what is the error, can anybody tell how i can apply this filter in js code instead of in the view??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to you to use the `$locale` service as a DI, using specifically the `$locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.MONTH` array.

Comment: how can i use it ...please...could give an exemple

Answer (score 0):

Please remove [ in

```
.filter('monthName', [function() {
```

to

```
.filter('monthName', function() {
```

Comment: thank you Sagar for your answer...but the problem is not in the filter because it works fine...the problem in the syntax in the view

Comment: chart-labels={{labelsf | monthName}}
to
chart-labels="{{labelsf | monthName}}"

Comment: same error:Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{labelsf | monthName}}] starting at [{labelsf | monthName}}].

Answer (score 0):

You can inject `$filter` in controller and use it like below:

```
function Ctrl($scope, $filter){
    $filter('monthName')(arg1);
}
```

Comment: the arg1 is the date?? if it is the case .. i tied this  $scope.labelsf.push($filter('monthName')(data.la_date)); it gives me undefiened

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/78adv82m/ look at the way i am applying filter here..